# Retrive records when div is half way scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am calling an ajax function to load a GridView when the div is scrolled till the bottom and my code is working fine but I want to call the function when the div is in halfway scrolled so that the user don't have to wait while fetching records.

**.ASPX HTML**

```
 <table class="Grid" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="Table1" style="width: 99%; border-collapse: collapse;">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 10%">ID</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 30%;">Title</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 20%;">Theme</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 14%;">Subject</th>
                <th scope="col" style="width: 14%;">Grade</th>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="dvGrid" style="height: 800px; overflow: auto; width: 100%">
            <asp:GridView ID="gridSearchResult" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="Grid" Width="99%" EmptyDataText="No records found!!!">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="tid" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-CssClass="tid" ItemStyle-Width="10%" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="Title" ItemStyle-CssClass="title" ItemStyle-Width="30%" HeaderStyle-Width="30%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="theme" HeaderText="Theme" ItemStyle-CssClass="theme" ItemStyle-Width="20%" HeaderStyle-Width="20%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="subject" HeaderText="Subject" ItemStyle-CssClass="subject" ItemStyle-Width="14%" HeaderStyle-Width="14%" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="grade" HeaderText="Grade" ItemStyle-CssClass="grade" ItemStyle-Width="14%" HeaderStyle-Width="14%" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
   //Load GridView Rows when DIV is scrolled
            $("#dvGrid").on("scroll", function (e) {
                var $o = $(e.currentTarget);
                if ($o[0].scrollHeight - $o.scrollTop() <= $o.outerHeight()) {

                    GetRecords();
                }
            });
```

What changes do I have to do in the above javascript function to call  **GetRecords()** when I scroll half of the Div.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply the height by 2, essentially like the container would be double its height.

```
$o[0].scrollHeight - $o.scrollTop() <= $o.outerHeight() * 2
```